# Swift Firestore Search for users

Tags: swift, firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore, querying

I've had already implemented a function to search for users using the `FirebaseDatabase` like that:

```
REF_USERS.queryOrdered(byChild: "username_lowercase").queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").queryLimited(toFirst: 25).queryStarting(atValue: text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
            {
                (snapshot) in
                snapshot.children.forEach(
                    {
                        (s) in
                        let child = s as! DataSnapshot
                        if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any]
                        {
                            let user = UserInfo.createUser(dict: dict, key: child.key)
                            if user.id! != currentUserId
                            {
                                completion(user)
                            }
                        }
                })
        })
```

But now I've decided to switch from the `Database` to `Firestore` and since they've been bragging about their great querying I figured it shouldn't be too hard but for a few days now I've been trying to figure out how to search for users and can't seem to get it done.

Thats the code I have so far:

```
REF_USERS.order(by: "username_lowercased").limit(to: 25).order(by: text).getDocuments
        {
            (snapshot, error) in
            snapshot?.documents.forEach(
                {
                    (s) in
                    let child = s

                    let user = UserInfo.createUser(dict: child.data(), key: child.documentID)
                    if user.id! != currentUserId
                    {
                        completion(user)
                    }
            })
        }
```

But like i said nothing really works.

Any suggestions? Id really appreciate it c:

-Marie

Answer (score 1):

First of all start by handling errors. Errors in Firestore are very descriptive and they will guide you what needs to be done in order for your query to work.

```
guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
    // Make your completion handler work with errors as well so you can read / display them
    // completion(nil, error)
    // For now just print the error
    print(error!)
    return
}
```

Also when you want to call a success completion handler when a condition is met, I suggest you just use a for loop and break when needed:

```
for document in snapshot.documents {
    if user.id! != currentUserId {
        completion(user)
        break
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay thank you but is it even possible to query based on a given string/text using firestore?

Comment: Yes, you can order by a string field in your document. So if you have a field called `username_lowercased` in your documents you should be able to order by it.

Comment: So I am doing it the right ways by saying `.order(by: "username_lowercased")` aswell as `.order(by: text)`? text is the text the user has typed

Comment: Do you have a `text` field as well?

Comment: But do you hold such field in your document?

Comment: oh sorry my bad. No I dont have a `text` field in my backend. Text is the ouput of a `textField` on one of my viewcontrollers.