# Do I need to separate a 'whereIn' and a field value that can contain two values in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying two fields in a document. I'm using the `whereIn`(that's what it's called in flutter, for web it's called `in`) operator for one field. The other field I need to query is a string. And I want to query this value against two values. Do I need to separate the queries or is there a way to do the full query in a single query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Firestore documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> You can use only one `in` or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't use both `in` and `array-contains-any` in the same query.

Since you need two `whereIn`/`in` clauses, you need to execute a separate query for each value in the second `whereIn` and then merge the results in your application code.

Comment: I just noticed that Peter showed the exact same quote in his answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561868/is-firebase-getdocument-run-line-by-line/61564335#61564335), so I'm not sure what your additional ask here is in top of that.